# How can i integrate my front-end applications with my BFF(back-end for front-end) by a private NPM services package?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, frontend

This package will be responsible for creating functions to consume all my BFF endpoints and return responses to the front-end project.

I intend to create the private package in Typescript and type the BFF responses, but, this is a problem, if the BFF contract changes, I would need to go to the package and refactor the type again and again.

What is the best solution for this? Is it really any good for me to create a private package for this or do I have another alternative?

Remembering that these endpoints would be consumed by several front-end projects, so, if I have a package for all of them I would avoid code duplication.

Comment: Can you explain the BFF abbreviation?

Comment: BFF = back-end for front-end

Comment: If your backend is written in TypeScript - I would highly recommend tRPC. I don't see a need for a private package to handle it, as the need to do so would indicate a huge issue for server-client communication in the JS/TS ecosystem - which I would say isn't there. Anyway, tRPC is a nice way to creating an api that's incredibly type-safe: https://trpc.io/